# Items with same name generating same keys when dragging

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd

I need the ability to have two of the same items while them not duplicating when dragged within the board. But when i drag in an item that exist in the board, it logs "moving".

It instead should add another same named item with different key. I have trouble locating my mistake, please help.

This is my code

```js
import { React, useState } from "react";
import { useDrop } from "react-dnd";
import { ItemTypes } from "../ItemTypes";
import Items from "./Items";

const Board = () => {
    const [components, setComponents] = useState([]);

    const onDelete = (id) => {
        console.log(components);
        console.log(id);
        setComponents(components.filter((component) => component.key !== id));
    };

    const [, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
        accept: ItemTypes.COMPONENT,
        drop: (item) => {
            console.log(item.name, item.key);
            if (item.key === undefined) {
                const { nanoid } = require("nanoid");
                const itemKey = { key: nanoid(16) };
                const newItem = Object.assign(item, itemKey);
                setComponents((components) => [...components, newItem]);
                console.log("add");
            } else {
                console.log("moving");
            }
        },
    }));

    return (
        <div ref={drop} className="board">
            <Items components={components} onDelete={onDelete} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Board;
```

this is component(external, should convert to item when dragged in)

```js
import React from "react";
import { useDrag } from "react-dnd";
import { ItemTypes } from "../ItemTypes";

const Component = ({ component }) => {
    const [, drag] = useDrag(
        () => ({
            type: ItemTypes.COMPONENT,
            item: component,
        }),
        []
    );

    return (
        <div ref={drag} className="component">
            <h4>{component.name}</h4>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Component;
```

This is Item(in the current board)

```js
import React from "react";
import { useDrag } from "react-dnd";
import { ItemTypes } from "../ItemTypes";
import { FaTimes } from "react-icons/fa";

const Item = ({ component, onDelete, key, left, top }) => {
    const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag(
        () => ({
            type: ItemTypes.COMPONENT,
            item: component,
            collect: (monitor) => ({
                isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
            }),
        }),
        [key, left, top]
    );

    if (isDragging) {
        return <div ref={drag} />;
    }
    return (
        <div ref={drag} className="item">
            <h4>
                {component.name}
                {<FaTimes onClick={() => onDelete(component.key)} />}
            </h4>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Item;
```

Comment: Can you add your drag logic? Also, your component where you generate key

Comment: key generator is in if block

Comment: On your drop console add one more property to see what value you are getting `console.log(item.name, item.key, typeof item.key);` . If the type of item.key is not undefined it will go to your else block. Generally you could change your condition to `if (item.key)` instead of checking for `undefined`.

Comment: I changed it to `if(!item.key)`, but everything is the same. I cant wrap my head around why `component` has key from `item`.

Comment: What's the value you got in console for `key` and `typeof key`?

Comment: `const newItem = Object.assign(item, itemKey);` change this to `const newItem = Object.assign({},item, itemKey);`

Comment: `Object.assign({},item, itemKey);` did work, can you ellaborate why in answer so i can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is how we use `Object.Assign()` correctly. It does at least 2 jobs.

1. Updates the existing object. `Object.assign(item, itemKey);` updates the item key.
2. Creates a new object `Object.assign({},item, itemKey);` This creates a completely new object as it merges old properties to an empty object.

You could have used the spread operator instead to avoid confusion.
`const newItem = {...item, itemKey};` would have worked.